# How can I do calculations with hexadecimal values with vim Macros?

Tags: expression-register

[How can I do calculations with vim Macros?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22400/how-can-i-do-calculations-with-vim-macros)

I have a question related to the above question ( how to do calculations in vim with an example of.csv), how can we achieve hexadecimal calculations with similar examples used in above question.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! In the future, it helps to move the relevant details from the link into the question so that the question stands alone (with the link for supporting content).

Comment: Be sure to read this if you haven't already: https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

Vim happily converts hex and octal number strings to decimal numbers when you use them in an arithmetic expression. So all you need to do is convert the arithmetic result back to a hex or octal formatted string.

Let's just modify the macro example from your linked answer. I'll use hex here. Octal is the same except for one character (see below). Here's the original macro sequence:

```
qa^"xywf,l"yywA,<C-R>=@x+@y<CR><Esc>+q
```

Here's the modified version:

```
qa^"xywf,l"yywA,<C-R>=printf("0x%x", @x+@y)<CR><Esc>+q
```

I just wrapped the arithmetic in a `printf()` call that has the hex conversion modifier `%x`. (Use `%X` if you want capital letters in the hex numbers.)

The line `0xf,0x2` will become `0xf,0x2,0x11`.

For octal use `%o` instead (e.g. `printf("0%o", ...)`).